# ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: col1 )

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

View :

`<%= link_to "Link", {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}, :update => "Ajaxcall", :remote => true %>`

Controller:

```
def AjaxView
   @vars= Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varName=> "one" },:select=>(params[:col]))
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

AjaxView.js

`$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var", :collection =>  @vars)) %>");`

_var.html.erb

`<%= var.col1 %>`

I am getting following error:
ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: col1 ):
    1: <%= var.col1 %>

Comment: in your contoller -  shouldn't  `@var=` read `@vars=` if not then your are passing a nil object to the `render`method, which of course has no col1 attribute

Comment: Thanks for pointing it Kai, it was typo I edited it now.

Comment: But I am still facing this issue, any help would be beneficial

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%= @var[0].col %> is the right answer
```